# How to filter result array from node-dir package

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the node-dir package (https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-dir) to list files recursively from a path but I cannot succeed to add a filter to my result.

For instance, I want in my result array only files with 'mp3' extension.
Does anyone know how I can do that?

```
    dir.files(__dirname, function(err, files.filter(ismp3file)) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(files);
});
function ismp3file(elmt){return element.substr((~-element.lastIndexOf(".") >>> 0) + 2) === "mp3";}
```

i tried to add filter, but i got an error.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dir = require('node-dir');

function isMp3File(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".mp3") > -1);
}

dir.files(__dirname, function(err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;
    files = files.filter(isMp3File);
    console.log(files);
});
```

Or if you prefer to verify the file *ends with* .mp3, you could add [`string.js`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/string) as a dependency:

```
var dir = require('node-dir'),
    S = require('string');

function isMp3File(file) {
    return (S(file).endsWith('.mp3'));
}

dir.files(__dirname, function(err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;
    files = files.filter(isMp3File);
    console.log(files);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking something like adding **option** in the files function such `dir.files(__dirname,{match: /.txt$/,exclude: /^\./},function(err, files) {....` but anyway it does the job well!

Comment: @user1128939 yeah, I saw that as an option, and was going to suggest doing that, but thought you wanted to use a filter instead.  Glad you got it working though!